# Starting directory for C-x C-f with emacs daemon

Tags: macos, mac, emacs

I recently switched over to using emacs as a daemon on OS X.  I added a launchd plist in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> 
 <plist version="1.0">
  <dict> 
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>gnu.emacs.daemon</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs</string>
      <string>--daemon</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ServiceDescription</key>
    <string>Gnu Emacs Daemon</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>grant</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

All works well except for one minor gripe when opening a file after a fresh emacsclient window has been opened via `emacsclient -c -n`.  When I hit <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>, it starts at the filesystem root rather than my home directory, whereas launching Emacs.app, <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> starts at my home directory.  Is there a way to switch the behavior to start at my home dir rather than the filesystem root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this page](http://trac.buildbot.net/wiki/UsingLaunchd), you should be able to add a working directory with this:

```
<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
<string>/Users/grant</string>
```

sub